# How do I change CSS properties while I am in another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a dark mode for my web application, which when clicked will change background color from black to white and white to black.

## I have a button for this dark mode, which when clicked does the following things:

1) calls a method which updates my state and changes the boolean value which further changes my class name for either light-mode or dark-mode
2) based on the class name I have a specific set of styles that could set the background color to either black or white.

## What have I done so far:

1) The button which I have created for changing mode is in a component called "Header.js".
2) In the Header component, I have other things such as the title and a form. And I am rendering my "Header.js" component to my "cardlist.js" component.
3) The Cardlist component contains my various cards of "cartoon characters"

## What is the problem:

The styles I want to change is in card list component, but I have my button in Header component. So do I access those class names?

My cardlist component:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Card from "./Card";
import Header from "./Header";
import "./Styles/CardList.scss";

class CardList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    // url: `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/${[...Array(494).keys()]}`,
    character: [],
    typedValue: ""
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    //const res = await axios.get(this.state.url);
    const ids = Array(493)
      .fill(null)
      .map((_, idx) => idx + 1)
      .join(","); // '1,2,3...,300'
    const url = `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/[${ids}]`;
    const res = await axios.get(url);

    this.setState({
      character: res.data
    });
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let typedValue = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ typedValue });
  };

  render() {
    const character = this.state.character;
    const typedValue = this.state.typedValue;
    let filter = character.filter(char => char.name.includes(typedValue));

    return (
      <div className="body-container">
        <Header />
        <div className="form-container">
          <form>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="title"
              placeholder="Search Characters"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </form>
        </div>

        <div className="cardlist-container">
          {filter.map(character => (
            <Card
              key={character.id}
              imgURL={character.image}
              id={character.id}
              name={character.name}
              status={character.status}
              species={character.species}
              type={character.type ? character.type : "Not Known"}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CardList;
```

My Header component

```
import React from "react";
import "./Styles/Header.scss";
import DarkMode from "./DarkMode";

class Header extends React.Component {
  state = {
    setClass: !JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Mode"))
  };

  handleChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      setClass: !this.state.setClass
    });
  };

  render() {
    localStorage.setItem("Mode", !this.state.setClass);
    let toggle = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Mode"));
    console.log(toggle);

    return (
      <div className="header-container">
        <div className="button-container">
          <div className="button-holder">
            {/* <button className="actual-button">DARK/LIGHT</button> */}
            <div className={toggle ? "dark-mode" : "light-mode"}>
              <button className="actual-button" onClick={this.handleChange}>
                DARK/LIGHT
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="heading__main">Rick and Morty Database</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: I think you need to put style in a state so that you can change from both screens you can use a redux to store at a single place. So that whenever click is happen then it will change the CSS at point that's how you can use redux to manage the CSS

Comment: In this kind of scenario ( Theming ), you should really make use of the [React context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). It will make your life a lot easier.